# Random variable is Big O in probability notation

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, limits-and-convergence

Let $R_n$ be a random variable with values in $[0,1]$ and $nR_n$ converges to $\frac{1}{1+C} \chi_m^2$ in distribution for some constant $C>0$ and $m\in \mathbb{N}$. Is it possible to show that $(1-R_n)^{-\frac{n-1}{2}} =O_P(1)$ holds?

I came across this result in the [proof of Theorem 3 of this paper](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejordan/courses/260-spring10/readings/liang-etal.pdf) but didn't really get it. Some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Its impossibe that $nR$ converges to this distribution. Is it $R_n$ or something similar?

Comment: I'm not sure if $R$ depends on $n$. But if we would assume so, is the conclusion then true?

Comment: Maybe the answer of Iosif Pinelis is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each natural $n$, let $R_n$ be random variable with values in $[0,1]$ such that $nR_n$ converges in distribution, as $n\to\infty$, to a random variable $X$ with a continuous cdf.

Let $T_n:=(1-R_n)^{-(n-1)/2}$. Take any real $t>1$. Then for all large enough natural $n$
$$t^{-2/(n-1)}=e^{-2\ln t/(n-1)}<1-\frac{\ln t}n$$
and hence
$$P(T_n>t)=P(nR_n>n(1-t^{-2/(n-1)})) \\
\le P(nR_n>\ln t)\underset{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow P(X>\ln t)
\underset{t\to\infty}\longrightarrow0.$$
So,
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}P(T_n>t)=0;$$
that is (cf. e.g. [equivalence (i)$\iff$(v) in Lemma 1](http://www2.math.uu.se/%7Esvante/papers/sjN6.pdf)), $(1-R_n)^{-(n-1)/2}=T_n=O_P(1)$, as desired.

---

The condition that $X$ has a continuous cdf (which actually holds in your setting) is not needed here, but with it the proof gets simpler just a little bit.

Comment: Thank you very much!